# Adding padding to yticklabels in pgfplots chart

Tags: pgfplots, labels, charts

In this MWE you can notice there's no padding between some of the labels and the chart itself. I'd like to add some space so the labels don't clash into each other. Adding some vertical padding below the chart on the x axis labels and some horizontal padding to the left labels will solve my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage\[backend=biber\]{biblatex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\[
    title={Densidad espectral},
    width=12cm,
    height=8cm,
    xlabel={\textbf{Distancia perceptual}},
    ylabel={\textbf{Ocupación del espacio espectral}},
    xmin=1, xmax=6,
    ymin=1, ymax=6,
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
    yticklabels={vacío, transparente, translúcido, opaco, comprimido, lleno},
    xticklabels={distante, , , , , lejano},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
\]
\addplot\[
    color=black,
    mark=square,
    \]
    coordinates {
    (1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4)(5,5)(6,6)
    };
    \legend{Densidad espectral}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I look forward to your answers!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Densidad espectral},
width=12cm, height=8cm,
xlabel={\textbf{Distancia perceptual}},
ylabel={\textbf{Ocupación del espacio espectral}},
xmin=1, xmax=6,
ymin=1, ymax=6,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
yticklabels={vacío, transparente, translúcido, opaco, comprimido, lleno},
xticklabels={distante, , , , , lejano},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
tick label style={inner sep=10pt},
]
\addplot[mark=square] coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) (5,5) (6,6)};
\legend{Densidad espectral}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Linear graph]

Comment: Thanks for that, I was really trying to find an easy solution and that delivered.